# Adding Array to Existing DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable, dtHOURS, that consists of two columns of data passed from an SQL database and I am trying to include a third column that consists of calculated values within the array, hours. I've looked at many similar asked questions, but none of the solutions seem to work in my case. I've confirmed that the correct values are being stored in the array, but I can't seem to populate those values within column "Total Hours". All the row data comes out blank for this column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
//Create new column and row for the "Total Hours" in data table
            DataColumn TotalHoursCol;
            DataRow TotalHoursRow;

            // Create new DataColumn, set DataType,
            // ColumnName and add to DataTable.
            TotalHoursCol = new DataColumn();
            TotalHoursCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
            TotalHoursCol.ColumnName = "Total Hours";

            // Add the Column to the Table.
            dtHOURS.Columns.Add(TotalHoursCol);




            //This loop calculates the total hours for all jobs and adds them to the data table
            for (int i = 1; i < numberOfRecordsHours; i++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(dtHOURS.Rows[i]["ID"]);
                //Console.WriteLine(dtHOURS.Rows[i]["ACT_RUN_HRS"]);

                if ((Convert.ToString(dtHOURS.Rows[i]["ID"])) == (Convert.ToString(dtHOURS.Rows[i-1]["ID"])))
                { 
                hours[i] = (Convert.ToDouble(dtHOURS.Rows[i]["ACT_RUN_HRS"])) + (hours[i-1]);

                    //Console.WriteLine(hours[i]);

                }
                else
                {
                    hours[i] = 0;
                    //Console.WriteLine("NEW JOB");

                }

                TotalHoursRow = dtHOURS.NewRow();
                TotalHoursRow["Total Hours"] = hours[i];
                dtHOURS.Rows.Add(TotalHoursRow);

                //Console.WriteLine(dtHOURS.Rows[i]["Total Hours"]);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the problem correctly, it looks like you are adding a new row instead of assigning to your new column.

Instead of

```
TotalHoursRow = dtHOURS.NewRow();
                TotalHoursRow["Total Hours"] = hours[i];
                dtHOURS.Rows.Add(TotalHoursRow);
```

Just put

```
dtHOURS.Rows[i]["Total Hours"] = hours[i];
```